# Switch case and generics checking

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a function that format `int` and `decimal` differently into string

I have this code:

and I want to rewrite it to generics:

```
    public static string FormatAsIntWithCommaSeperator(int value)
    {
        if (value == 0 || (value > -1 && value < 1))
            return "0";
        return String.Format("{0:#,###,###}", value);
    }

    public static string FormatAsDecimalWithCommaSeperator(decimal value)
    {
        return String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", value);
    }


    public static string FormatWithCommaSeperator<T>(T value) where T : struct
    {
        string formattedString = string.Empty;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            if ((int)value == 0 || (value > -1 && value < 1))
            return "0";

            formattedString = String.Format("{0:#,###,###}", value);
        }

        //some code...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the number is an int - returned format is without decimal digits
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string FormatNumberTwoDecimalDigitOrInt(decimal value)
    {
        return (value == (int)value) ? FormatAsIntWithCommaSeperator(Convert.ToInt32(value)) : FormatAsDecimalWithCommaSeperator(value);
    }
```

How can i use T in the function body?

What syntax should I use?

Comment: Why not just have two overloads? I'm guessing there is a reason for this but from your example I'd rather have two methods instead of switching on type.

Comment: Why do you use generics here? Is your method usable for ANY struct, even for one I defined myself?

Comment: Generics are not helpful here, you might as well use *object* as the argument type.  Note how the code is the practically the same.

Comment: Do you simply want the decimal place to be ommited if the value has no fractional part?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the [TypeCode enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx) for switch:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
{
    case TypeCode.Int32:
       ...
       break;
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
       ...
       break;
}
```

Since C# 7.0 you can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching):

```
switch (obj)
{
    case int i:
       ...
       break;
    case decimal d:
       ...
       break;
    case UserDefinedType u:
       ...
       break;
}
```

Beginning with C# 8.0 you can use [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression):

```
string result = obj switch {
    int i => $"Integer {i}",
    decimal d => $"Decimal {d}",
    UserDefinedType u => "User defined {u}",
    _ => "unexpected type"
};
```

Comment: What about user types?

Comment: How would you use the second pattern when you have `T` and not `obj`? (i.e., when you know the type and you do not have an instance of that type).

Comment: This is not generic types

Answer (score 54):

Another way to do switch on generic is:

```
switch (typeof(T))
{
    case Type intType when intType == typeof(int):
        ...
    case Type decimalType when decimalType == typeof(decimal):
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

Note that [`when` as a case guard in `switch` expressions was introduced in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#case-guards)/Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 44):

In modern C#:

```
public static string FormatWithCommaSeperator<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case int i:
            return $"integer {i}";
        case double d:
            return $"double {d}";
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if I only got the T but not a value of T ? say

    public T Get<T>(string name){  }

Comment: You could use use `default(T)`. But I'm not sure if that's faster then just having a dictionary with key type. If what you want is a keyed collection that returns different types, just keep the value as the common base type (or Object), and either do a direct cast in get that throws, or use `as` which returns null. that's perfect behaviour, doing the type check won't save you any code, and only complicate error handling.

Comment: Correcting myself, The default(T) solution won't work for ref types, because the default is null. So you'll have to just test the type with, or probably just find a better design.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar question, but with custom classes rather than built-in data types. Here's how I went about it:

```
switch (typeof(T).Name)
{
    case nameof(Int32):
        break;
    case nameof(Decimal):
        break;
}
```

I modified it to use the types you are using (i.e., int and decimal). I like this approach more than hard coding strings, as a refactor of a class name will not break this code.

With newer versions of C#, you could also do this some of the time:

```
switch (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)))
{
    case int _:
        break;
    case decimal _:
        break;
}
```

I say "some of the time" because that would only really work with types that have a default constructor. This approach uses pattern matching and discards. I don't really like it since you need to create an instance of the object (that you then throw away) and because of the default constructor requirement.

Answer (score 9):

If you have an object, you can use C# 7 **pattern matching**. But if you don't have an object and want to switch on a generic type T, the best and fastest solution is just a ternary **if** operator.

```
public string TernaryIf<T>() =>
    typeof(T) == typeof(int) ? "#,###,###" :
    typeof(T) == typeof(decimal) ? "#,###,###.##" :
    null;

public string TrueSwitch<T>() =>
    true switch
    {
        true when typeof(T) == typeof(int) => "#,###,###",
        true when typeof(T) == typeof(decimal) => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string DefaultSwitch<T>() =>
    default(T) switch
    {
        int => "#,###,###",
        decimal => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string When_Switch<T>() =>
    typeof(T) switch
    {
        Type _ when typeof(T) == typeof(int) => "#,###,###",
        Type _ when typeof(T) == typeof(decimal) => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string TypeCodeSwitch<T>() =>
    Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)) switch
    {
        TypeCode.Int32 => "#,###,###",
        TypeCode.Decimal => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string WhenSwitch<T>() =>
    typeof(T) switch
    {
        Type intType when intType == typeof(int) => "#,###,###",
        Type decimalType when decimalType == typeof(decimal) => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string NameOfSwitch<T>() =>
    typeof(T).Name switch
    {
        nameof(Int32) => "#,###,###",
        nameof(Decimal) => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };

public string ActivatorSwitch<T>() =>
    Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) switch
    {
        int => "#,###,###",
        decimal => "#,###,###.##",
        _ => null,
    };
```

**Benchmarks**:

| Method | Time |
| --- | --- |
| TernaryIf | 0.37 ns |
| TrueSwitch | 0.37 ns |
| DefaultSwitch | 0.48 ns |
| When_Switch | 1.92 ns |
| TypeCodeSwitch | 3.85 ns |
| WhenSwitch | 3.96 ns |
| NameOfSwitch | 7.98 ns |
| ActivatorSwitch | 12.10 ns |

Comment: Thanks palota this saved me from writing some disgusting code which I very much wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

### **Edit: If you only want to handle exactly int and double, just have two overloads:**

```
DoFormat(int value)
{
}

DoFormat(double value)
{
}
```

---

If you insist on using generics:

```
switch (value.GetType().Name)
{
    case "Int32":
        break;
    case "Double":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

**OR**

```
if (value is int)
{
    int iValue = (int)(object)value;
}
else if (value is double)
{
    double dValue = (double)(object)value;
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: You're right. I updated the post (added object cast). Anyways, I like the answer of Nikola better anyways - its much more readable.

Comment: `public T myMethod<T>(T value) where T : object` is fine too, and you dont need cast!!

Answer (score 6):

From [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) it's possible to do it this way which also works with [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types):

```
switch ((Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T)).Name)
{
    case nameof(Int32):
        ...

    case nameof(Decimal):
        ...

    case nameof(Boolean):  // You can also switch types like 'bool' or Nullable 'bool?'
        ...

    case nameof(String):   // Why not to use 'string'?
        ...

    default:
        ...
}
```

If you prefer [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) you can use:

```
return (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T)).Name switch
{
    nameof(Int32) => ...,
    nameof(Decimal) => ...,
    nameof(Boolean) => ...,  // You can also switch types like 'bool' or Nullable 'bool?'
    nameof(String) => ...,   // Why not to use 'string'?
    _ => ...,
};
```

Comment: This (unfortunately) seems to be the cleanest option still, assuming there's no naming conflicts. It bothers me that C# doesn't directly support this.

If you're not using value types like `int` or not worried about `Nullable<?>`, then this can even be simplified to just the `typeof(T).Name` as the value, which is makes this much shorter and easier to read than other options, none of which really seem better than just using if-else statements to check the type.

Answer (score 5):

more formatted way to do switch on generic is:

```
switch (true)
{
    case true when typeof(T) == typeof(int):
        ...
    case true when typeof(T) == typeof(decimal):
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

Comment: ...this might as well just be `if(typeof(T) == typeof(int)) ... else if(typeof(T) == typeof(decimal)) ... else ...`, right?

Comment: @ShelbyOldfield Yes, but some people might like switch case style pattern more. it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could always do:

```
public static string FormatWithCommaSeparator<T>(T[] items)
{
    var itemArray = items.Select(i => i.ToString());

    return string.Join(", ", itemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the variabele;

```
    public static string FormatWithCommaSeperator<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            // Do your int formatting here
        }
        else if (value is decimal)
        {
            // Do your decimal formatting here
        }
        return "Parameter 'value' is not an integer or decimal"; // Or throw an exception of some kind?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of using generics use IConvertible

> ```
>     public static string FormatWithCommaSeperator(IConvertible value)
>     {
>             IConvertible convertable = value as IConvertible;
>             if(value is int)
>             {
>                 int iValue = convertable.ToInt32(null);
>                 //Return with format.
>             }
>             .....
>     }
> ```

Comment: the line `IConvertible convertable = value as IConvertible;` seens redundant to me.

Answer (score 0):

In [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) you can use (replace "..." with the relevant code):

```cs
... type switch
{
    Type _ when type == typeof(int) => ...,
    Type _ when type == typeof(decimal) => ...,
    _ => ... // default case
};
```

Another elegant option (replace "..." with the relevant code):

```cs
... Type.GetTypeCode(type) switch
{
    TypeCode.Int32 => ...,
    TypeCode.Decimal => ...,
    _ => ...
};
```

For more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression