# SonarLint: Why does this condition always evaluates to true?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, sonarlint, switch-expression

I'm writing a generic extension function which parses a string value to other types. The function basically looks like this:

```cs
public static T Parse<T>(string input)
{
    T result = (T)(typeof(T) switch
    {
        Type t when t == typeof(DateOnly) => DateOnly.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        _ => Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T))
    });

    return result;
}
```

*Note that this is simply a snippet which demonstrates the issue.*

I got the case guard from this post (since I haven't used those before) and changed it to a switch expression:

[Switch case and generics checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802325/switch-case-and-generics-checking)

However the line with the case guard produces the warning `S2589: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'True'.` Note that I'm using Sonar Lint for C# linting. The warning generates a green squiggly line under `Type t`:

[image: squiggly line]

The function seems to work as intented even if I add more types to be parsed differently.

So my question is: Is this an issue with Sonar Lint or am I missing something with case guards?

Comment: Looks like a Sonar Lint bug - or maybe the version you're using doesn't understand that construct?